# Wordpress Domain Mapping shows new domain in place but takes me to the sub domain

Tags: multisite, domain-mapping

I have multiple domains that run on the same IP address in media temple.

I input this IP "8.5.06.06" into the "domain mapping" server ip. I then set up the "domains" section and selected the "id" of my subdomain "demo.abc.com" I would like mapped and put in my domain "cba.com" and deselected "primary"

It displays the domain "cba.com" the subdomain "demo.abc.com" is mapped to, but when I go to "visit site" it takes me to the subdomain "demo.abc.com" I clicked on and not the mapped domain "abc.com"

This is driving me crazy! Am I missing something?

Thanks for your patience, I am a complete noob at this

Comment: bump... anyone?

Comment: Generally, you did the right steps.  Did you try setting the domain to primary?  That is how we do ours.